# Como rolar uma lista <ul> até a minha <li> específica após selecionar um item que carrega a página novamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma lista `<ul>` com diversas `<li>`, quando um item é selecionado esta `<li>` recebe um id "selected".

```
<ul id="lista-produtos">
  <li>produto 1</li>
  <li>produto 2</li>
  <li id="selected">produto 3</li>
  <li>produto 50</li>
</ul>
```

Quando clico em um `<li>`, ele recarrega a página e seleciona o elemento correspondente na lista. Porém, precisaria que a lista rolasse até o elemento selecionado após a seleção do item. Podem me ajudar?

Tentei utilizar o código abaixo com scrollTop, porém sem sucesso.

```
$('#lista-produtos').scrollTop($('#selected:nth-child()').position().top);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para rolar até um elemento específico você pode utilizar:

```
document.getElementById('selected').scrollIntoView();
```

Resposta baseada em: [Scroll / Jump to id without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266746/scroll-jump-to-id-without-jquery)

Comment: usando o scrollIntoView(); funcionou! obrigado!